# How to pass value of a dropdownlist in ajax url

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, fusioncharts

I have the following script which is used to render a chart:

```js
var num = 'five';

function drawColumn() {
  $(function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: 'http://localhost/Admin/chart_data.php?num=' + num,
      type: 'GET',
      success: function(data) {
        chartData = data;
        var chartProperties = {
          "caption": "Top 10 wicket takes ODI Cricket in 2015",
          "xAxisName": "Player",
          "yAxisName": "Wickets Taken",
          "rotatevalues": "1",
          "theme": "fint"
        };
        alert('chart rendered');
        apiChart = new FusionCharts({
          type: 'column2d',
          renderAt: 'chartContainer',
          width: '500',
          height: '300',
          dataFormat: 'json',
          dataSource: {
            "chart": chartProperties,
            "data": chartData
          }
        });
        apiChart.render();

      }
    });
  });
}
```

The html which will invoke this function is as follows:

```html
<select name="select1" onchange="num=this.value;drawColumn();">
  <option value="five">Five</option>
  <option value="all">All</option>
</select>
```

The chart gets rendered the first time when the page gets loaded. However, it is not rendered when the options are changed in the dropdown list. Where am I going wrong? Please help

Comment: try adding console.log('fire'); right inside your function, then open your console and look for it when you change your drop down.

Comment: try removing `$(function() {` as this is shorthand for _document.ready_

Comment: removing $(function() { worked for me, thank you so much :)

Comment: Voting to close this as off-topic "While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers."

Comment: Don't use self-invoking functions unless you need to invoke it for first time.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a document ready handler inside of a function call does not work.  This is due to the fact that the document ready event has previously fired and will not fire once again, thus the function never executes the contents.

```
function drawColumn() {
  $(function() {//document ready handler
  ...code here
  });
}
```

proper:

```
function drawColumn() {
      ...code here
}
```

**EDIT: suggestions**

Rather than this:

```
<select name="select1" onchange="num=this.value;drawColumn();">
  <option value="five">Five</option>
  <option value="all">All</option>
</select>
```

This

```
<select id="select1" name="select1">
  <option value="five">Five</option>
  <option value="all">All</option>
</select>
```

Then this:

```
$(function() {
  $('#select1').on('change', drawColumn);
  function drawColumn(data) {
    var num = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
      url: 'http://localhost/Admin/chart_data.php?num=' + num,
      type: 'GET'
    }).done(function(data) {
      var chartData = data;
      var chartProperties = {
        "caption": "Top 10 wicket takes ODI Cricket in 2015",
        "xAxisName": "Player",
        "yAxisName": "Wickets Taken",
        "rotatevalues": "1",
        "theme": "fint"
      };
      alert('chart rendered');
      var apiChart = new FusionCharts({
        type: 'column2d',
        renderAt: 'chartContainer',
        width: '500',
        height: '300',
        dataFormat: 'json',
        dataSource: {
          "chart": chartProperties,
          "data": chartData
        }
      });
      apiChart.render();
    });
  }
});
```